# Forcing form re-submission when user presses back button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a search function on my web page and want to force form re-submission when the user presses the back button.

Here is the flow of information...

Search Page > Display Results Page > Product Page

Currently when a user is on the Product Page and presses the back button, they receive the following error on the Display Results Page (Chrome):
"Confirm Form Resubmission ERR_CACHE_MISS"

I would like the page to resubmit the form automatically so the user's original search results are displayed on the Display Results Page.

Preferably I would like to do this without using $_GET, if at all possible.

edit: The following code did not work.

```
if(isset($_POST['query'])) {
$_SESSION['query'] = $_POST['query'];
}
else {
$_POST['query'] = $_SESSION['query'];
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for not wanting to use $_GET ? just curious.

Comment: I did not want to use $_GET due to SEO considerations. I plan to have links with predetermined queries. Using $_GET would cause there to be many new urls (i.e. www.example.com/q=abcd or q=efgh and so on) and I believe Google would follow those links and index those pages. Sure, I could just put noindex on the page... but that would be relying on Google to not index the page, this way I can force them to only have my search.php page indexed once. Only problem I can foresee is it may cause Google to ignore the other links on my page to search.php (which I need it to go to to index product pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following answer and working code - this seems like the path of least resistance to me. This code should go on the "display results" page for anyone having the same issue.

```
header('Cache-Control: no cache');
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the input value to a session so when the user presses back, the value is still there and use ajax/jquery to populate the result page.